# How to use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider in standalone application?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, illuminate-container

I am calling the register method of the respective service provider, but the actual boot method is not firing and ultimately not triggering the observer.

```
$app = new \Illuminate\Container\Container();
$app['app'] = $app;
with(new \MyNameSpace\Providers\AppServiceProvider($app))->register();
```